# How to use the Freeze() and Thaw() functions in wx.TextCtrl?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using this code:

```
self.output = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", style=wx.TE_RICH2 |
                              wx.TE_MULTILINE |
                              wx.TE_READONLY  |
                              wx.TE_NOHIDESEL |
                              wx.TE_AUTO_URL)
```

**PROBLEM IS:**

The self.output object is updating continuously,The screen every time is going down.I am not able to read the first lines.If scroll up reading lines that time  self.output  object is updated ,that window screen coming down.
Attached the  screen shot.[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtUW1.png)

**NEED SOLUTION:**

I will create an button.When click the button window don't go down if the self.output object updating also (Means text can be update on the window but can't go down).if unchecked out the button window can be go down and when the self.output object getting update time.

I know by using freeze() and Thaw() function,I can restrict the feature.I tried different ways it's not working me.

If any solution is appreciable.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: you are calling SetValue somewhere and so generating an event.  Use [ChangeValue](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_entry.html#a8c52ab71f51c8f80556c2c8e763cbca1) instead to change the text without generating the event.

Comment: Can you explain with one example.I am updating the test by using the self.output.write(" ").By using write method updating the data in window.

Comment: Try using ChangeValue as I suggest in the answer.